# Как вычислить количественно прокрутку страницы с помощью jquery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Есть кнопка, которую надо прятать при прокрутке страницы на 50px вниз и снова показывать при прокрутке страницы на 50px вверх:

```
<button class="add">+</button>
```

Как это реализовать с помощью jquery?

Comment: Покажите, что вы пытались сделать и что у вас не получилось?

Comment: 50px вверх и вниз относительно чего?

Comment: Относительно начального положения, когда прокрутка остановилась

Answer (score 1):

Можно сделать через добавление класса.

```js
(function() {
  var isFixed = false;
  var $element = $('.but');
  var $elementWrapper = $('.but_wrap');
  if ($elementWrapper.get(0).getBoundingClientRect().top <= 0) {
    isFixed = true;
    $element.addClass('hide');
  }
  $(window).on('scroll', function(event) {
    var position = $elementWrapper.get(0).getBoundingClientRect();
    console.log(position.top);
    if (position.top <= 50 && !isFixed) {
      isFixed = true;
      $element.addClass('hide');
    } else if (position.top > 50 && isFixed) {
      isFixed = false;
      $element.removeClass('hide');
    }
  });
})();
```

```css
.but {
  position: fixed;
  display: block;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="but_wrap">
  <div class="but">+</div>
</div>
<div class="lorem">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Incidunt totam explicabo, quos consectetur, recusandae non praesentium, tempore qui sed eveniet distinctio sapiente vitae architecto optio modi nesciunt, soluta quis minima. Lorem ipsum dolor sit
  amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Omnis unde velit id beatae sunt possimus, fugiat modi repellendus vel, odio vitae ducimus officia doloribus error magnam? At, aperiam distinctio odit molestiae totam exercitationem? Consectetur hic, rerum impedit
  quidem alias, numquam modi excepturi, quia, mollitia nemo architecto beatae! Placeat autem iste a consequuntur, dolore aperiam at soluta id facere repudiandae, neque nemo natus quis earum ducimus quia enim quibusdam dignissimos hic dolores voluptatem
  numquam dicta. Voluptatem optio quas dolores doloremque! Tempora culpa rerum quas quae quidem ipsa odit voluptatem aperiam earum doloribus ullam eum, ad, natus consequatur neque. Numquam, quibusdam, corporis! Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
  adipisicing elit. Possimus dolorem sapiente exercitationem doloremque incidunt distinctio commodi quos neque dicta iste ducimus sint adipisci quod cupiditate beatae ipsa debitis deserunt, iure earum eligendi voluptatem harum quas. Praesentium id reprehenderit
  error repellat corporis, eligendi alias omnis animi distinctio ratione recusandae. Consequuntur explicabo, eligendi vel libero laborum unde, aspernatur doloremque non adipisci officiis, nemo expedita quasi nulla nobis dolore. Inventore excepturi nemo
  iste minima voluptatem suscipit ut sed, hic, quod vel veniam qui totam a quis consequatur dolor neque sunt! Porro quam iusto, laborum dolore voluptas repellendus numquam eveniet, nihil earum itaque vel aspernatur nisi, officiis mollitia eaque non sapiente
  quia enim, ex animi! Minus facere architecto doloremque ipsam veniam sapiente odio accusamus eveniet, unde delectus voluptate sunt in consectetur culpa pariatur hic. Odio reiciendis magni dolores, laboriosam recusandae debitis illo cum magnam voluptates
  aperiam veniam asperiores sint molestias consectetur labore illum quidem nihil, sit ad modi. Voluptatibus consequuntur totam, ipsum officiis. Iusto magni sequi, laboriosam quisquam adipisci quam sunt natus veritatis. Veritatis iste quae magni eveniet
  enim, illo adipisci numquam temporibus excepturi soluta iure earum neque reprehenderit. Nisi labore ut beatae, eligendi sed error soluta hic. Repellendus magnam blanditiis nihil similique est eum cumque provident eius praesentium quisquam, sunt voluptatibus
  libero, fuga rerum saepe alias aliquid, odio assumenda. Eaque quas nulla deleniti aliquam dignissimos aliquid aperiam, modi eos deserunt, amet vitae! Molestias voluptate dolorum quam, cupiditate aliquid accusantium quasi commodi, repellat doloribus,
  dolor et culpa deserunt asperiores incidunt nostrum sequi magni voluptas. Veritatis quas ex quia possimus nisi et, sint, perspiciatis, beatae amet doloribus vitae, delectus distinctio laboriosam incidunt. Quaerat minima, facilis. Explicabo asperiores
  dolores officiis, sapiente molestiae, magni id nesciunt quasi sunt laudantium totam placeat, sed est doloremque! Voluptas deserunt natus distinctio, quibusdam, porro iure ex, magni dignissimos cupiditate doloribus explicabo. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
  consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempora dolor, at exercitationem possimus omnis ab, perferendis id corporis quo non perspiciatis. Distinctio, numquam. Officia, provident eum in, doloribus inventore eos modi ratione totam eligendi amet illum culpa tempora
  iure qui distinctio illo obcaecati quis, mollitia necessitatibus delectus aspernatur. Excepturi vel ab ea, dignissimos labore animi beatae laudantium, minus ullam impedit repellat, tempore voluptate corporis quis! Ratione ad ipsam, natus. Atque voluptate
  quam deserunt iure, delectus perspiciatis veniam, quaerat ea necessitatibus ipsa iste numquam praesentium corrupti ullam nulla molestias tempora, reiciendis natus? Quasi voluptatibus recusandae omnis maiores harum asperiores deleniti fuga commodi excepturi
  alias consectetur, sequi modi ea fugit, laudantium quod dolor, sunt neque. Consequuntur vero similique quis quae? Consequatur voluptas, ratione delectus doloribus necessitatibus cum iure asperiores molestias quod totam dolorem exercitationem quibusdam,
  nam aspernatur atque ipsam consequuntur animi optio suscipit ipsum! Delectus, cumque quod perferendis saepe officiis vitae et iusto voluptate non velit, voluptatem culpa nobis laborum, aliquam nam ea temporibus eaque. Maiores magnam obcaecati vero cumque
  nostrum voluptatibus, ipsa quis deleniti ex tempore, dignissimos, repudiandae dolore saepe fugit ab delectus quos id a explicabo aperiam eveniet nulla nemo! Voluptatem, eaque eius aliquam molestiae esse quae. Dolor totam a aut, ea aliquid mollitia minima
  maxime maiores, sapiente vero unde ad ipsum voluptas voluptatibus rem, quibusdam architecto impedit laudantium asperiores odio aperiam quis atque? Vel sunt explicabo eveniet debitis rerum excepturi consequatur nisi accusamus qui vitae aliquid maxime
  dignissimos expedita alias blanditiis, ratione odio magnam, ex labore aspernatur dolorum maiores earum nihil. Inventore nemo, eveniet quos ipsam mollitia minima dicta sit accusamus, aperiam qui vero eius, ratione corporis provident repudiandae vel laborum
  quidem. Ipsa nam, sunt beatae, rem quis delectus, necessitatibus ut, facere veniam repellendus doloribus quidem cum qui libero veritatis numquam culpa explicabo quibusdam itaque accusantium laudantium expedita doloremque. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
  consectetur adipisicing elit. Vel eligendi, repellat at itaque magnam nisi ad. Repudiandae, nulla, similique. Id enim numquam sunt est, nisi sequi quis modi atque pariatur. Cum praesentium ipsam aut laboriosam, dolorum? Dolor odit aliquid molestiae
  repellendus. Recusandae, repudiandae. Atque nostrum praesentium accusamus maxime mollitia, asperiores eaque aspernatur molestiae, accusantium earum blanditiis excepturi hic ratione quae magni rerum reprehenderit laudantium expedita corporis quas dolorem
  deleniti distinctio autem suscipit. Possimus ut, adipisci dolores voluptatem nisi modi repellendus cupiditate nostrum quibusdam iusto asperiores distinctio, illo temporibus, hic tempora maxime dolorum assumenda repellat beatae veniam consequatur labore
  quis voluptate.
</div>
```